# Alamofire XML request to PropertyList

Tags: swift, xml, alamofire, codable

I am trying to parse an XML data using Codable from the sample https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml.

My struct is

```
struct Note: Codable {
  var to: String?
  var from: String?
  var heading: String?
  var body: String?
}
```

However if I make the following request I get the error `responseSerializationFailed : ResponseSerializationFailureReason` **"PropertyList could not be serialized because of error:\nThe data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml")
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, encoding: PropertyListEncoding.default).responsePropertyList { (response) in
  guard response.error == nil else {
    print(response.error!)
    exp.fulfill()
    return
  }

  print(response)

  if let data = response.data {
    print(data)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    let note = try! decoder.decode(Note.self, from: data)
    print(note)
  }
}
```

How do you exactly work with the responsePropertyList in Alamofire?

Comment: Incorrect format ? Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461607/decode-propertylist-using-swift-4-codable-propertylistdecoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Apple's *Codable* protocol does not have a way to decode XML. While a Plist is XML, XML is not necessarily a Plist unless it follows a certain format.

While there are plenty of third party libraries, I would suggest you take a look at the [XMLParsing library](https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing). This library contains a **XMLDecoder** and a **XMLEncoder** that uses Apple's own *Codable* protocol, and is based on Apple's JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder with changes to fit the XML standard.

Link: https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing

---

**W3School's XML To Parse:**

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**Swift Struct conforming to Codable:**

```
struct Note: Codable {
    var to: String
    var from: String
    var heading: String
    var body: String
}
```

**XMLDecoder:**

```
let data = Data(forResource: "note", withExtension: "xml") else { return nil }

let decoder = XMLDecoder()

do {
   let note = try decoder.decode(Note.self, from: data)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

**XMLEncoder:**

```
let encoder = XMLEncoder()

do {
   let data = try encoder.encode(self, withRootKey: "note")

   print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

There are a number of benefits for using Apple's *Codable* protocol over that of a third-party's protocol. Take for example if Apple decides to begin supporting XML, you would not have to refactor.

For a full list of examples of this library, see the Sample XML folder in the repository.

---

There are a few differences between Apple's Decoders and Encoders to fit the XML standard. These are as follows:

**Differences between XMLDecoder and JSONDecoder**

1. `XMLDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy` has an extra case titled `keyFormatted`. This case takes a closure that gives you a CodingKey, and it is up to you to provide the correct DateFormatter for the provided key. This is simply a convenience case on the *DateDecodingStrategy* of JSONDecoder.
2. `XMLDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy` has an extra case titled `keyFormatted`. This case takes a closure that gives you a CodingKey, and it is up to you to provide the correct data or nil for the provided key. This is simply a convenience case on the *DataDecodingStrategy* of JSONDecoder.
3. If the object conforming to the Codable protocol has an array, and the XML being parsed does not contain the array element, XMLDecoder will assign an empty array to the attribute. This is because the XML standard says if the XML does not contain the attribute, that could mean that there are zero of those elements.

**Differences between XMLEncoder and JSONEncoder**

1. Contains an option called `StringEncodingStrategy`, this enum has two options, `deferredToString` and `cdata`. The *deferredToString* option is default and will encode strings as simple strings. If *cdata* is selected, all strings will be encoded as CData.
2. The `encode` function takes in two additional parameters than JSONEncoder does. The first additional parameter in the function is a *RootKey* string that will have the entire XML wrapped in an element named that key. This parameter is required. The second parameter is an XMLHeader, which is an optional parameter that can take the version, encoding strategy and standalone status, if you want to include this information in the encoded xml.

Answer (score 0):

PropertyList files although are in XML format, they need to follow Apple's PropertyList DTD: http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd

If you want to map a regular XML file (that do not follow PropertyList DTD) into a model object and you don't mind using an external library you can try [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper).

You model for this XML should look like this:

```
class Note: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var to: String?
    var from: String?
    var heading: String?
    var body: String?

    required init(map: XMLMap) { }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        to <- map["to"]
        from <- map["from"]
        heading <- map["heading"]
        body <- map["body"]
    }
}
```

And you can map it from string using `XMLMapper`:

```
let note = XMLMapper<Note>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Or if you install `Requests` subspec you can use `responseXMLObject(queue:keyPath:mapToObject:completionHandler:)` function like:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml")
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, encoding: XMLEncoding.default).responseXMLObject { (response: DataResponse<Note>) in
    let note = response.result.value
    print(note?.from ?? "nil")
}
```

Hope this helps.