# How to convert plist file to array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, plist

I am a beginner programmer and I'm in the process of learning swift.  I have an excel file that contains multiple rows and columns that have strings and integers, converted it to a plist file, and imported it into Xcode.  How can I read in the plist file in Swift and be able to display a row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode PropertyList using Swift 4 Codable PropertyListDecoder()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461607/decode-propertylist-using-swift-4-codable-propertylistdecoder)

Comment: Please [update/edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58382731/edit) your answer with all of the relevant code to meet the [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).